# Can't start npm on Windows 8 (Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm')

Tags: node.js, npm

I just installed Nodejs on my new computer with Windows 8. I can't get npm to work on it. Although the node server starts fine:

Here's the error:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Source\Project>npm install 
Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm'


C:\Users\User\Documents\Source\Project>npm start
Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm'


C:\Users\User\Documents\Source\Project>
```

Comment: Manually creating a folder named 'npm' in the displayed path fixed the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Latest version is not compatible with windows 8. Just download this files and it works in my windows 8 perfectly.
http://blog.nodejs.org/2014/06/16/node-v0-10-29-stable/

Comment: Why would an older version work with Windows 8 but not the latest version? Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Actually I dont have any Idea.Sometime it is not compatible with new visions.I have also fallen this problem with xampp.I think it is the best solution..

Comment: Let's see, the accepted answer is pointing to an unknown binary on a file drop site.  Brilliant.

Comment: Please do not edit this back to your link. There's an official source, and I've changed it back to that.

Answer (score 85):

you can try to create 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm' folder.

Comment: Did that. It worked too. But there are problems in the individual modules. For example: grunt doesn't work at all.

Comment: This seems to be the correct solution. I tried downgrading to the above 0.10.29 but it looks like all you have to do is create your npm folder and all is well

Comment: Creating new folder solved the problem :D

Comment: Works on Node 0.10.31 on Windows 8.1 so far as getting you over that error, but still logs that it's missing the file `C:\Windows\System32\package.json`. Creating this however, still doesn't work.

Comment: That should be the correct solution! Worked for me!